VirtualBox: Guest system losing focus when clicking in other monitor
I use VirtualBox 7.1.0r164728 on Ubuntu, with a Windows guest. I have two monitors on that system and I use full screen mode on both monitors. I notice that when I click with the mouse on the non-primary screen, it causes the VM to lose focus, i.e. I need to use the host keys in order to put focus in the VM again. This is quite annoying. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can prevent it?
